# Android Google Maps Overlay image from URL

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Recently I try to use Overlay in Google Maps v2 for Android, from some tutorials  we knows that

```
BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.android);
GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(image)
                .position(point1, 500f)
                .transparency(0.5f);
googleMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);
```

The problem i face is: can i overlay a image from URL? Like:

```
BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.android);
            GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(***"http://image path...."***)
            .position(point1, 500f)
            .transparency(0.5f);
            googleMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to get `BitmapDescriptor` object form Internet, so you can try use `Picasso` library load the image for the Internet.

Sample code:

```
    GroundOverlayOptions mGroundOverlayOptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        new AddGroundOverlay().execute(MY_URL);
        ...
    }


public class AddGroundOverlay extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, BitmapDescriptor> {

    BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor;

    @Override
    protected BitmapDescriptor doInBackground(String... url) {
        myUrl = url[0];
        try {
            bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(myUrl).get());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmapDescriptor;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(BitmapDescriptor icon) {

        try {

            GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(bitmapDescriptor)
                    .position(point1, 500f)
                    .transparency(0.5f);
            // Updated
            mGroundOverlayOptions = groundOverlay;
            googleMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to bjiang reply! I have another question, if i want this AsyncTask to return GroundOverlay Object, how? Because, i'll remove this overlay after some events happened, thx!

Comment: I think you can just create a member variable for `GroundOverlay` Object, and save it in `onPostExecute`before `googleMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);` See my update in the code.

Comment: what's about overlaying a set of images? where should i add the for-loop?

Comment: thanks to bjiang again! i tried to add for-loop successfully, but the problem i face now is that my .gif seems not to be tranparent on the google map... kind of weird